# AWS Cloud9 and Lambda Alias

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloud9

I am trying to understand how AWS Cloud9 works with AWS Lambda alias and version system.

When deploying a lambda from Cloud9, does it always deploy on $LATEST ? 
When importing a lambda in Cloud9, does it always import $LATEST ?

Can we choose versions ?
Can we choose alias ?

If this is somewhere is the doc, sorry, I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The **Lambda** section of the **AWS Resources** window in the AWS Cloud9 IDE currently does not provide any features for working with Lambda function versions or aliases. Instead, you can use the terminal in the IDE to run the AWS CLI and AWS SAM CLI with the corresponding commands, actions, and arguments. For details, see the following:

- [Introduction to AWS Lambda Versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-intro.html) in the *AWS Lambda Developer Guide*
- [Introduction to AWS Lambda Aliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/aliases-intro.html) in the *AWS Lambda Developer Guide*
- [Managing Versioning Using the AWS Management Console, the AWS CLI, or Lambda API Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/how-to-manage-versioning.html) in the *AWS Lambda Developer Guide*